# What is this invisible character in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Here is the test case:

```
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "%Tasks"
   ...> ;  
quote(meta_sheet_name)|length(meta_sheet_name)
'Tasks'|5

sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "Tasks%"
   ...> ;  
quote(meta_sheet_name)|length(meta_sheet_name)
'Tasks'|5

sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "Tasks"
   ...> ;  
sqlite>
```

For some reason the last query does not return the row and the others do. Here is the SQLite documentation on the `SELECT` statement https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html and I could not find anything more specific that documents the `LIKE` usage.

---

Additional debugging information:

SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668

Explain query plans

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "%Tasks"
   ...> ;  
selectid|order|from|detail
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE data AS calendar_tasks USING COVERING INDEX data_index (~500000 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT

sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "Tasks%"
   ...> ;  
selectid|order|from|detail
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE data AS calendar_tasks USING COVERING INDEX data_index (~500000 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT

sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "Tasks"
   ...> ;  
selectid|order|from|detail
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE data AS calendar_tasks (~500000 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

Explains

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "%Tasks"
   ...> ;  
addr|opcode|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|comment
0|Trace|0|0|0||00|
1|OpenEphemeral|1|0|0|keyinfo(2,BINARY,BINARY)|08|
2|Goto|0|20|0||00|
3|OpenRead|2|3|2|keyinfo(3,BINARY,BINARY)|00|
4|Rewind|2|18|1|0|00|
5|String8|0|2|0|%Tasks|00|
6|Column|2|1|3||00|
7|Function|1|2|1|like(2)|02|
8|IfNot|1|17|1||00|
9|Column|2|1|2||00|
10|Function|0|2|4|quote(1)|01|
11|Column|2|1|3||40|
12|Function|0|3|5|length(1)|01|
13|Found|1|17|4|2|00|
14|MakeRecord|4|2|1||00|
15|IdxInsert|1|1|0||00|
16|ResultRow|4|2|0||00|
17|Next|2|5|0||01|
18|Close|2|0|0||00|
19|Halt|0|0|0||00|
20|Transaction|2|0|0||00|
21|VerifyCookie|2|37|0||00|
22|TableLock|2|2|0|data|00|
23|Goto|0|3|0||00|

sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "Tasks%"
   ...> ;  
addr|opcode|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|comment
0|Trace|0|0|0||00|
1|OpenEphemeral|1|0|0|keyinfo(2,BINARY,BINARY)|08|
2|Goto|0|20|0||00|
3|OpenRead|2|3|2|keyinfo(3,BINARY,BINARY)|00|
4|Rewind|2|18|1|0|00|
5|String8|0|2|0|Tasks%|00|
6|Column|2|1|3||00|
7|Function|1|2|1|like(2)|02|
8|IfNot|1|17|1||00|
9|Column|2|1|2||00|
10|Function|0|2|4|quote(1)|01|
11|Column|2|1|3||40|
12|Function|0|3|5|length(1)|01|
13|Found|1|17|4|2|00|
14|MakeRecord|4|2|1||00|
15|IdxInsert|1|1|0||00|
16|ResultRow|4|2|0||00|
17|Next|2|5|0||01|
18|Close|2|0|0||00|
19|Halt|0|0|0||00|
20|Transaction|2|0|0||00|
21|VerifyCookie|2|37|0||00|
22|TableLock|2|2|0|data|00|
23|Goto|0|3|0||00|

sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT quote(meta_sheet_name), length(meta_sheet_name)
   ...>   FROM calendar.data calendar_tasks
   ...>   WHERE calendar_tasks.meta_sheet_name LIKE "Tasks"
   ...> ;  
addr|opcode|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5|comment
0|Trace|0|0|0||00|
1|OpenEphemeral|1|0|0|keyinfo(2,BINARY,BINARY)|08|
2|Goto|0|20|0||00|
3|OpenRead|0|2|2|38|00|
4|Rewind|0|18|0||00|
5|Column|0|37|2||00|
6|Column|0|1|3||00|
7|Function|0|2|1|like(2)|02|
8|IfNot|1|17|1||00|
9|Column|0|1|2||00|
10|Function|0|2|4|quote(1)|01|
11|Column|0|1|3||40|
12|Function|0|3|5|length(1)|01|
13|Found|1|17|4|2|00|
14|MakeRecord|4|2|1||00|
15|IdxInsert|1|1|0||00|
16|ResultRow|4|2|0||00|
17|Next|0|5|0||01|
18|Close|0|0|0||00|
19|Halt|0|0|0||00|
20|Transaction|2|0|0||00|
21|VerifyCookie|2|37|0||00|
22|TableLock|2|2|0|data|00|
23|Goto|0|3|0||00|
```

Comment: Originally I thought the % was matching an invisible character. That prompted the question name.

Comment: What SQLite version you're using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in 3.22.0.

Comment: Documentation of LIKE usage: https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like

Comment: This does look pretty weird! Could you post `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <your query...>` and `EXPLAIN <your query...>` for all three queries?

Comment: Thank you. Added debugging information.

Comment: Use `hex()` instead of `quote()` to see if any bytes are there that aren't displaying. Also upgrade to a current version; 3.7 is ancient. Lots of bug fixes and improvements since.

Comment: Also, what affinity does the `meta_sheet_name` column have?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you really want to know what actually happening from the SQLite perspective is, use the following command

```
sqlite> .show
```

This will list all the default settings for the respective database

```
       echo: off
        eqp: off
    explain: auto
    headers: off
       mode: list
  nullvalue: ""      /* This setting is set to empty string */
    output: stdout
colseparator: "|"
rowseparator: "\n"
    stats: off
    width:
```

Actually the **nullvalue** is set to empty, hence you will see the all the null values as an empty string

```
nullvalue: ""
```

In case if you want to see any other character in the place of empty string then you can use the following way to set it up. But it will be temporary until you exit the database.

You can set it as follows:

```
.nullvalue NULL
```

Now it will start showing empty strings as NULL similar to that of MySql